# Error while initiating Yeoman generator

Tags: command-line, permissions, npm

When I was trying Yeoman generator using [this link](https://github.com/colekettler/generator-flask-api#getting-started), I got the following error message:

```
root@SYSGSOFT:/home/sysg_soft# yo flask-api  
/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:53  
                                throw err;  
                                ^  
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/root/.config/configstore/insight-yo.json'   
You don't have access to this file.  
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:577:33)  
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:483:33)    
    at Configstore.get (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:34:26)   
    at Configstore.get (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:81:14)   
    at Insight.get (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/lib/index.js:48:22)  
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js:197:48)   
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)  
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)  
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To  initiate the flask-api Yeoman generator run the command `yo flask-api` as regular user, not as root user.